# Using specific network interface in C# with VLC ActiveX Plugin

Tags: c#, vlc

I'm working now on the IPTV program in C#. As a media engine I'm using a VLC ActiveX Plugin. Data goes over UDP protocol.

Now I ran into the problem.
I have several networking interfaces. For example, I have Local Area Connection, that is used for network and Internet access, and VirtualBox Network.
First connection has an IP-address of 10.10.10.2 and second - 192.168.1.2.
When I trying to join multicast-group, some of IGMP-queries go through the VirtualBox Network instead of Local Area Connection. So I don't receive a multicast-traffic.

I need to choose specific interface (Local Area Network) for my application. So all data will going through this network interface.
I found some answers in the Internet, but not specifically for my problem.

Here's something, that I was trying to use:

```
IPAddress localAddress = IPAddress.Parse("10.10.10.2");
IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(localAddress, 0);
Socket client = new Socket(localEndPoint.AddressFamily, SocketType.Raw, ProtocolType.Igmp);
client.Bind(localEndPoint);
axVLCPlugin21.playlist.add("udp://@239.1.9.2:1234", axVLCPlugin21, null);
axVLCPlugin21.playlist.play();
```

But it's not working. Can someone help me, please?

Thank you!

Comment: How is it not working? Do you receive and error / exception? Getting no results? Unexpected results?

Comment: IGMP-queries still continue to go through VirtualBox interface (192.168.1.2). So I don't receive any data. There's no erorr. 
But I need to choose my Local Area Network connection for all network actions.

Comment: I remember seeing somewhen that there was a way to list all network interfaces in C#, then filter them to select automatically the local network one. You might want to look into that.

Comment: Yes, I can list netwok interfaces, for example, using:
`NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()`
and `GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses`.
But I can't get the app to work through needed interface

Comment: When determining which address to bind on for your socket, you should just then get the local IP from that interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally did it! I make a socket and bind it using my needed network interface. After that, I send IGMP-query using this socket and then receive data over needed network interface.

Now I'm using this code:

```
        Socket mcastSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
        IPAddress localAddress = IPAddress.Parse("10.10.10.2");
        IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(localAddress, 0);
        mcastSocket.Bind(localEndPoint);

        IPAddress mcastAddress = IPAddress.Parse("239.1.9.2");
        MulticastOption mcastOption = new MulticastOption(mcastAddress, localAddress);
        mcastSocket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.AddMembership, mcastOption);

        axVLCPlugin21.playlist.add("udp://@239.1.9.2:1234", axVLCPlugin21, null);
        axVLCPlugin21.playlist.play();
```